Leaflet touch event doesn't work if the map is active
I am trying to drag a circlemarker with my fingers over a leaflet map, using touch events. I found an example online that works pretty well, but just because, for some reason, I can load the map (tile) it uses.
When I replace this map for a working one, I am not able to drag the circle with my fingers anymore. The function 'onCircleDown' is not called when I touch the circlemarker on the screen.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Eventtest</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    circle = L.circleMarker([51.508, -0.11], {
        radius: 50,
        color: 'black',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap);

    circle.on('mousedown touchstart', onCircleDown);
    
    function onCircleDown (e1) {
        mymap.dragging.disable();
        var mouseStartingLat = e1.latlng.lat;
        var mouseStartingLng = e1.latlng.lng;
        var circleStartingLat = e1.target._latlng.lat;
        var circleStartingLng = e1.target._latlng.lng;
        circle.on('mousemove', function (e2) {
                var mouseNewLat = e2.latlng.lat;
                var mouseNewLng = e2.latlng.lng;
                var latDifference = mouseNewLat - mouseStartingLat;
                var lngDifference = mouseNewLng - mouseStartingLng;
                var currentCircleCoords = L.latLng (circleStartingLat + latDifference, circleStartingLng + lngDifference);
                e1.target.setLatLng (currentCircleCoords);
        });
        circle.on ('mouseup', function () { 
                    circle.off('mousemove');
                    mymap.dragging.enable();
                });
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>

Here a working tile
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'

I have been looking for some explanation and solutions for hours in vane.
